# Emberjs Routing: link-to not working as expected

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

In my app I have a few different routes

```
Profile.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource('index', { path: '/:user' });
 this.resource('followers', { path: '/:user/followers' });
 this.resource('following', { path: '/:user/following' });
});
```

In my template for index, I have a - `{{#link-to 'followers'}} Followers {{/link-to}}`. When I click this link, the url changes to /user/followers and I get a console log - "Attempting transition to followers" but nothing happens thereafter. The transition doesn't complete and I still see the template for index route, not for followers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a route and template defined for followers?